# Getting the contents from wpf datagrid control into a data table

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, datagrid, datatable

I'm trying to make an app for work where I enter some data into some controls (start date and end date wage week ) and then the user picks a csv extract from our wage program. The app then merges the data from the controls and the csv file into a datatable which is then set as the datacontxct of the wpf datagrid view.

```
this.dgCSVData.DataContext = oDS.Tables[0].DefaultView;
```

So as I under stand it the datagrid is now  bound (that is a question not a statement) Here is a screen shot [image: screenshot of loaded data]

The datagrid is in the "shape" of the datatable in the sql database I want to append the data to. However the datatable was created in a private event handler CSV_Load_Click, code block below.

What I had  hoped to do is set another button event handler up call "Upload Data" and pass the datatable (oDS.Tables[0].DefaultView) to the DAL layer to be read and appended to sql database table, the problem is how do I make the datatable available, should I have created a class to match my data row  and then created a public list of the rows?

```
private void CSV_Load_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //Turn on upload button
    btUpload.IsEnabled = true;

    //To load and display CSV data
    //string filename = txFilePath.Text;
    string delimStr = ",,";
    char[] delimiter = delimStr.ToCharArray();
    string strFilePath = txFilePath.Text;
    DataSet oDS = new DataSet();
    string strFields = null;
    DataTable oTable = new DataTable();
    DataRow oRows = null;
    Int32 intCounter = 0;
    oDS.Tables.Add("Property");
    StreamReader oSR = new StreamReader(strFilePath);
    //Go to the top of the file
    oSR.BaseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    string File = fileTest;
    //System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(File.ToString());

    //Add in the Header Columns check if headers in first row
    if (rbYes.IsChecked==true)
        // action for headers in row 1
    {
        foreach (string strFields_loopVariable in oSR.ReadLine().Split(delimiter))
        {
            strFields = strFields_loopVariable;
            oDS.Tables[0].Columns.Add(strFields);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (File==@"CHHOURS.CSV")
        {
            string TitleHeaders = "Wage_Year,Wage_Start_Date,Wage_End_Date,Tax Week,Wk_No,Clock,Surname,Initial,Dept,Dept_Hours,Other_Hours,Total_Hours,OT_Hours,";
            foreach (string strFields_loopVariable in TitleHeaders.Split(delimiter))
            {
                strFields = strFields_loopVariable;
                oDS.Tables[0].Columns.Add(strFields);
            }  
        }           
        else
        {
            Int32 i = 0;
            foreach (string strFields_loopVariable in oSR.ReadLine().Split(delimiter))
            {
                string ColumLetter = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

                strFields = ColumLetter[i].ToString();
                oDS.Tables[0].Columns.Add(strFields);
                i += 1;
            }
        }
    } 


    //String request = oSR.ReadToEnd();
    //Now add in the Rows
    oTable = oDS.Tables[0];
    while ((oSR.Peek() > -1))
    {
        oRows = oTable.NewRow();

        if (File == @"CHHOURS.CSV")
        {
            oRows[intCounter] = cbWageYear.Text;
            intCounter = intCounter + 1;
            oRows[intCounter] = dpStartDate.SelectedDate;
            intCounter = intCounter + 1;
            oRows[intCounter] = dpEndDate.SelectedDate;
            intCounter = intCounter + 1;
            oRows[intCounter] = cBTaxWeek.SelectedIndex;

            intCounter = intCounter + 1;
        }
        foreach (string strFields_loopVariable in oSR.ReadLine().Split(delimiter))
        {
            strFields = Convert.ToString(strFields_loopVariable);
            if (intCounter < 20)
            {
                oRows[intCounter] = strFields;
                intCounter = intCounter + 1;
            }
            else
            {

            }
        }

        intCounter = 0;
        oTable.Rows.Add(oRows);
    }

    this.dgCSVData.DataContext = oDS.Tables[0].DefaultView;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I woke up this morning with an idea and It worked .wow!

All I did was declare my dataset as public before the constructor of my class. Now there might be a "better" way but that worked for me. Ii have been able to call my update method from my DAL and create a datareader, so now just the update to sql to do, then bug fixing.

I am almost happy :)

here is the code

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
{



    public List<TaxWeek> LTaxWeeks { get; set; }

    public TaxWeek SelectedTaxWeek { get; set; }

    **public DataSet oDS = new DataSet();**


    public MainWindow()

    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```